# react-select How to hide dropdown menu programmatically when 'no results found' is shown?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Github Repo: [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

After searching in the select box:

[image]

After typing a text that is not in the dropdown and enter is pressed. I want to hide the dropdown box.

My implementation:

```
<Select
        ref={ input => this.input = input }
        name="form-field-name"
        searchable
        autoBlur
        clearable={false}
        openOnFocus
        onInputKeyDown={this.onInputKeyDown.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        options={this.props.items}
/>
```

using `onInputKeyDown` I am detecting enter keycode. What do I do to remove the dropdown there when 'No results found' is shown?

```
onInputKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === keys.ENTER) {            
        console.log('on input key down');
        // How to detect 'No results found' shown?
        // And then, how to close the dropdown?
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Select component is that exactly? Considering that you have a ref added, you could probably do this.input.blur(). Triggering a blur event on the dropdown will remove focus from it and probably automatically close it.

Comment: This is the repo https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select only `.focus()` works and `.blur()` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and try to get back with a solution.

Comment: still no answer?

Comment: Nope. Maybe they have improved this in v2. But it's in beta. Don't know about it though

Answer (score 33):

In V2 you can achieve this by setting `noOptionsMessage` to a function that returns `null`:

```
<Select noOptionsMessage={() => null}/>
```

This will prevent the fallback option from displaying completely. Note that setting `noOptionsMessage` to `null` directly will result in an error, the expected prop type here is a function.

Comment: i wanted to hide it only when the input is empty (for autocomplete), so i used: `noOptionsMessage={(e) => e.inputValue ? 'No options' : null}`

Answer (score 4):

**First method:**
Turn off `<Menu />` component to hide dropdown list.

```
    <Select
      components={{
        ...components,
        Menu: () => null
      }}
    />
```

**Second method:**
Turn off dropdown conditionally. e.g. When there is no value in input.

```
// Select.js
import { Menu } from './Menu'
  <Select
    {...props}
    components={{
      Menu
    }}
  />

-------
// Menu.js
import { components } from 'react-select'
export const Menu = props => {
  if (props.selectProps.inputValue.length === 0) return null

  return (
    <>
      <components.Menu {...props} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `noResultsText` prop. Set it to `null` whenever you would want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the menu when no more options are available you can try to override the `MenuList` component. This worked for me:

```js
const MenuList = ({ children, ...props }: MenuListProps) => {
  return Array.isArray(children) && children?.length > 0 ? (
    <components.MenuList {...props}>
      {children}
    </components.MenuList>
  ) : null;
};
```